# CSS to manipulate 6 div in a 3 column layout

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a layout with 6 div, to a 360 grid layout, each have different lengths with same width. First row of 3 div are aligned at top, Second row of div are also aligned along their tops, however not the result I want.

As the middle div in the top middle has less content (less length then top left and right) I would like the lower middle div to move up the column to reduce the space between the two middle div's.

Current code, based on 12 column 960:

```css
html {
 background: url(../img/bg.jpg) repeat;
}

body {
 color: #0194a6;
 font-family: cinnamon_cakeregular, Ubuntu, helvetica;
 text-align: center;
}

/* GENERAL STYLES */

a {
 color: white;
}

h4, .desc {
 color: #000000;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
 padding-top: 10px;
}

#desc li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#container1 {
 position: relative;
 padding-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html long="en">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv-"Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <title>Marita Jordaan Photography ~ Pricing</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/960.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/text.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/price.css" type="text/css" />
 
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container1" class="container_12"> <!--start container-->
  <div id="upper"><!--start upper-->
   <div class="grid_4"><!--start col1-->
   <img src="img/newborn.jpg" alt="Newborn" />
    <h4> Basic - R1 600 </h4>
   
   <ul id="desc">
    <li> Babies 0 - 3 months old </li>
    <li> Baby only - no parents and/or siblings </li>
    <li> 2 - 3,5 hour shoot </li>
    <li> 20 - 30 high resolution images on disk </li>
    <li> In studio </li>
    <li> (Twins R1 900) </li>
   </ul>
   
    <h4> Deluxe - R1 900 </h4>
    
   <ul id="desc">
    <li> Babies 0 - 3 months old </li>
    <li> Include parents with up to 2 siblings </li>
    <li> 3,5 - 4,5 hour shoot </li>
    <li> 30 - 40 high resolution images on disk </li>
    <li> In studio / On location </li>
    <li> (Twins R2 200) </li>
   </ul>
   </div><!--end col1-->
   
   <div class="grid_4"><!--start col2-->
    <img src="img/1stcake.jpg" alt="1st Birthday Cake Smash" />
   
    <h4> Basic - R1 300 </h4>
   
   <ul id="desc">
    <li> 1 year only </li>
    <li> 1 - 1,5 hour shoot </li>
    <li> 15 - 20 high resolution images on disk </li>
    <li> In studio </li>
    <li> (Parents to supply cake
      all other props will be supplied) </li>
   </ul>
   </div><!--end col2-->
  
   <div class="grid_4"><!--start col3-->
   <img src="img/fam.jpg" alt="Family" />
   
    <h4> Basic - R1 500 </h4>
   
   <ul id="desc">
    <li> 1 - 1,5 hour shoot </li>
    <li> Family of 3 - 4 </li>
    <li> (R250 per extra family member) </li>
    <li> 20 - 30 high resolution images on disk </li>
    <li> On location /li>
   </ul>
   
    <h4> Deluxe - R1 800 </h4>
   
   <ul id="desc">
    <li> 1,5 - 2 hour shoot </li>
    <li> Family of up to 8 members </li>
    <li> 30 - 40 high resolution images on disk </li>
    <li> On location </li>
   </ul>
   </div><!--end col3-->
  </div><!--end upper-->
  </div><!--end container1-->
 
 <div id="container2" class="container_12"> <!--start container2-->
  <div id="lower"><!--start lower-->
   <div class="grid_4"><!--start lcol1-->
    <img src="img/baby.jpg" alt="Baby" />
   
    <h4> Basic - R1 300 </h4>
   
   <ul id="desc">
    <li> Babies 3 -12 months old </li>
    <li> 1 - 2 Babies ~ no parents </li>
    <li> 1 - 2 hour shoot </li>
    <li> 20 - 30 high resolution images on disk </li>
    <li> In studio / On location </li>
   </ul>
   </div><!--end lcol1-->
  
   <div class="grid_4"><!--start lcol2-->
   <img src="img/preg.jpg" alt="Pregnancy" />
   
    <h4>Basic - R1 100</h4>
   
   <ul id="desc">
    <li> 45 min - 1 hour shoot </li>
    <li> Parents only </li>
    <li> 15 - 20 high resolution images on disk </li>
    <li> In studio / On location </li>
   </ul>
   
    <h4> Deluxe - R1 350 </h4>
   
   <ul id="desc">
    <li> 1,5 - 2 hour shoot </li>
    <li> Parents with up to 2 siblings </li>
    <li> 20 - 30 high resolution images on disk </li>
    <li> On location </li>
   </ul>
   </div><!--end lcol2-->
  
   <div class="grid_4"><!--start lcol3-->
   <img src="img/other.jpg" alt="Other" />
    
    <h4> OTHER </h4>
   
    <ul id="desc">
     <p> This includes, but not limited to
       parties and events.
       Customised around your requirements.
       Quote supplied on request </p>
    </ul>
    
     <h4> EXTRAS </h4>
   
    <ul id="desc">
     <li> High quality printed photobooks </li>
     <li> Any size prints </li>
     <li> Canvas </li>
     <p> Contact me if you would like to include
       any of these products into your package </p>
    </ul>
    </div><!--end lcol3-->
   </div><!--end lower-->
    </div> <!-- end container2-->
 
    <div id="divider" class="container_12">
   <div class="grid_12"><!--start dcol1-->
   <img src="img/heart-div.png" alt_"Heart Divider" />
   
   </div><!--end fcol1-->
  </div>
     <div id="footer" class="container_12">
   <div class="grid_12"><!--start fcol1-->
   <img src="img/bot_pastel.png" alt="Bottom Border" />
   
   </div><!--end fcol1-->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can't re-use IDs on the same page (did you mean to use a class instead?), however, I suspect , from the description that you don't actually want rows, just columns.

I made the demo below to illustrate the fact that rows aren't really what you are after.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/sf32z262/)

Note: I'm not using 960gs here for brevity but I'm sure you can see that it has the layout you require. All you have to do is adapt it to the 960gs classes etc.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px dotted green;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 30%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.box {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #bada55;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.short {
  background: rebeccapurple;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box short"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box short"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. Possibly I was overthinking it as a old dog trying to learn new tricks. Will apply the code as the basis for another layout.

And yes, possibly I did mix class with ID's